# Writing CKEditor edited HTML file from PHP

Tags: php, html, format, save, ckeditor

I'm using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and I want to save the HTML edited to a file. In order to do so, I use the following code:

```
if (isset($_POST['editor']) && !empty($_POST['editor']))
{
    $data = $_POST['editor'];
    $path = "uploads/".generateRandomString().".html";
    $file = fopen($path, "w"); 
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
}
```

The problem is that if I edit something in the editor and the source code is:

```
<p><img alt="" src="http://zns.india.com/upload/2013/12/29/PITBULL319.jpg" style="height:351px; width:319px" /></p>
```

when I save it to the file, the source code turns out to be:

```
<p><img alt="\&quot;\&quot;" src="\&quot;http://zns.india.com/upload/2013/12/29/PITBULL319.jpg\&quot;" style="\&quot;height:351px;" width:319px\"=""></p>
```

I guess it's a formatting issue but I don't know how to solve it. Even trying to replace the `\&quot` (which is actually deisplayed as `\"`) it stills doesn't look identical.

I would appreciate any kind of advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: html_entity_decode might help you here.

Comment: I've just tried it and it doesn't make any difference. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If I use utf8_encode by modifying the following line: `$data = utf8_encode($_POST['editor']);`, nothing changes. Is that what I am suposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `stripslashes()` function. `$data = stripslashes($_POST['editor']);`

The problem was in the `magic_quotes` that PHP automatically enables. Thanks all!